# Most efficient method of getting Crobat in Pokémon HG SS?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

I would like to know what is the best efficient method to get *Crobat* in Pokémon Crystal, Gold, Silver, Soul Silver or Heart Gold.

I have tried to make my lvl 51 Golbat happy, but it don't evolves, and I don't know what to do now. I need a form of getting a Crobat in less than 2 days. Thanks.

Comment: You mention two distinct generations of games, each with different mechanics. I've gone with the fourth-gen tag, as it was in your title, but let me know if you really meant second gen.

Comment: @RavenDreamer You're right, I only saw GenII titles and missed the point. As the question is about an specific Pokémon evolution, that in this case, is the same in all generation above GenI (because in GenI he does not evolve) I changed the tag again.

Comment: @MichelAyres Yes, but the * available methods* to raise happiness varies, which is why the generation matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are exactly two ways to get a Crobat:

1. Get a Golbat to 220 [friendship](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship), then level it up.
2. Trade for one.

If it doesn't evovle, then it's not happy enough. The most efficient approach depends on how far you are from the target; if you're very close, then a [haircut](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Haircut_brothers) might do the trick, or a grooming from Daisy.

You also need to take into account which generation *you're actually playing*: HeartGold and SoulSilver are 4th generation, and use different mechanics.

Assuming that you're really playing HG/SS, as your question title suggests, you can get a lot of friendship points very quickly if you have a steady supply of EV berries and money to burn on vitamins; refer to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship#Generation_IV) for exact numbers. However, this necessarily disrupts any EV training you may have performed, so you have to determine if that approach is worth it.

If you are able to dump your saved game, you can check the current friendship level exactly and plan the best strategy based on how far you have to go; you can also [approximate the friendship level](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship#Friendship_raters); the NPC in Goldenrod City near the bike shop is probably the most easily accessible one.

Comment: Those EV berries are: Pomeg, Kelpsy, Qualot, Hondew, Greppa, and Tamato Berries. The Soothe Bell also doubles the amount of happiness gained. You can find one in the National Park, located north of Goldenrod City.

Answer (score 3):

You can **only** evolve [Golbat](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Golbat_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) into [Crobat](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Crobat_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) you need level his happiness (Friendship) independent of your Generation (besides the first), but as @MichaelMadsen pointed in [his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/65539/12936), you can get a Crobat in a trade.

- [How you can level the friendship in GenII.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship#Generation_II)
- [How you can level the friendship in GenIV.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship#Generation_IV)

**GenII**

- Gold
- Silver
- Crystal

**GenIV**

- Diamond
- Pearl
- Platinum
- HeartGold
- SoulSilver

### Why my Golbat is not evolving in Crobat, even with high happiness

1. Check if your Golbat is holding an [Everstone](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Everstone#Everstone)
2. Your happiness may not be as high as you think. remember, you lose happiness every time you let your pokemon die, put him in the PC, etc (check the How you can level the friendship link above).

Answer (score 2):

Generally when the NPC In Goldenrod say "I've got the feeling your Pokemon really trusts you" You're at that stage where you can level it to 25 and it will evolve, I had my Zubat since level 2 and i just finished the 4th gym. It's had a sooth bell since before the third gym when I picked it up in the National Park.

Answer (score 0):

I discover a new way of getting a Crobat, and I made a video explaining it. Here it is: [How to catch Crobat on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-r6v7PqM2w)

> You need to do this steps to get the Crobat:
>
> 1. Get a "Grn Apricorn" (Green apricorn).
> 2. Go to Kurt's house in Azalea Town (Who makes the PokéBalls).
> 3. Give him a "Grn Apricorn" and wait a day. If you do this before 12:00 p.m. you only have to wait a few minutes.
> 4. Go to Ecruteak City to the Burned Tower(Where Entei, Raikou and Suicune appeared for the first time) and search for a Zubat.
> 5. Catch it with The Friend Ball that Kurt gave to you.
> 6. Level it up 9-11 levels, and you'll get the Crobat.

Answer (score 0):

The friendship balls really are the best method. I caught a level 16 golbat in the patch of grass west of mahogany with a friendship ball and its happiness rating starts at like 210 I think. After I caught it, I gave it one each of calcium, protein, iron, carbos, and HP up. Then, I gave it a rare candy, and it evolved. That's the best method. This is on the silver version, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want one, you can give Kurt a GRN Apricorn and wait until it turns into a friend ball. Catch a golbat with the friend ball. Give it a soothe bell and a haircut in the tunnel in Goldenrod to level it up.

If it doesn't evolve, give it another haircut until it evolves. Good luck. I was lucky because in the beginning of the game I caught a zubat and leveled it up, evolved it and followed these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Catch a Golbat with a Friend Ball and bike up and down in Goldenrod City to near the day-care 40 to 45 times and level up your Golbat.